# PySpark Group the Dataframe by Year

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a column of date and a column of count.
eg:

```
Date       Count: 
3/07/2010  1
2/01/2010  2
1/07/2012  5
```

I used the code below to change to the data type to date:

```
func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'), DateType())
crime_mongodb_df = crime_mongodb_df.withColumn('Reported Date', func(col('Reported Date')))
```

Then, I want to group the data by year and find the total count per year. I am not sure how to do the grouping.
Can I get some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use functions from `pyspark.sql.functions` to do all of this, including type change quite easily :)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col, year

df = spark.createDataFrame([('3/07/2012', 1), ('2/07/2010', 2), ('1/07/2010', 5)], ["Date", "Count"])

df.show()
df.printSchema()
+---------+-----+
|     Date|Count|
+---------+-----+
|3/07/2012|    1|
|2/07/2010|    2|
|1/07/2010|    5|
+---------+-----+

root
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Count: long (nullable = true)
```

```
adjustedDf = df.withColumn("Date", to_date(col("Date"), "d/MM/yyyy"))\
    .withColumn('year', year("Date"))

adjustedDf.show()
+----------+-----+----+
|      Date|Count|year|
+----------+-----+----+
|2012-07-03|    1|2012|
|2010-07-02|    2|2010|
|2010-07-01|    5|2010|
+----------+-----+----+
```

```
adjustedDf.groupBy("year").sum("Count").show()

+----+----------+
|year|sum(Count)|
+----+----------+
|2010|         7|
|2012|         1|
+----+----------+
```

Comment: Oh right - sorry. Misformatted the answer and imports got lost. You need to import ```from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date, col, year``` to use those functions

Comment: Thanks! It works! But, I already converted the date string to date using udf(Two lines code in the question). Is it possible to modify the code to use my code to first convert the date then grouping? @Daniel

Comment: Well, yes, but built-in spark functions for parsing should be much more efficient than manually creating udf with python calls. You can use withColumn, like in your question ```crime_mongodb_df.withColumn('Reported Date'', func(col('Date')))``` - note that first argument to ```withColumn``` is the name of newly created column. Still, I'd very much advise against doing it and to use ```to_date```

Comment: Thanks! I have a last question. How I I get the list of values in adjustedDf? Such as: [2010,2012] or [7,1]

Comment: Depens what you want to do with them. To load data intro driver and use it as regular python variables you can run ```coll = df.collect()``` and then e.g. ```[row.year for row in coll]``` but if you have a lot of data this can crash your driver. Usually for large amounts of data you would write the result into a file, database or any other store.